# Request for proof of the following identity.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How do we establish the following identity?
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)) \sqrt{\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)}} \,d{\theta} \\
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} &\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^{+} \,,\, b \rightarrow (\frac{\pi}{2})^{-}} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{(\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)) \sqrt{\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)}} \,d{\theta} \\
= &\pi.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we recall that $\sin(\theta)=\tan(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ then:

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1 + \tan(\theta)) \sqrt{\tan(\theta)}} \frac{\,d{\theta}}{\cos^2(\theta)}$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1 + \tan(\theta)) \sqrt{\tan(\theta)}} \,d[\tan(\theta)]$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + z) \sqrt{z}} \,dz=\pi$$

Comment: How did you determine the value of  that last integral?

Comment: As $ \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} [{\tan^{-1}}(\sqrt{x})] = \frac{1}{2(1 + x) \sqrt{x}} $, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have $ \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{(1 + x) \sqrt{x}} \,dx = 2[{\tan^{-1}}(\sqrt{b}) - {\tan^{-1}}(\sqrt{a})] $.